# How to transfer PC audio to Bluetooth

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth, dell-inspiron

I got Jabra Bluetooth, and I paired with my Bluetooth device which is inbuilt in the system: Dell Inspiron 7520 SE.

When I view the Volume Mixer Properties, I see the following:

[image]

I checked my Device manager and in that all Bluetooth devices are there, and Services are already running.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for us to know how to help you since you did not give us a model of Jabra headset.

**Nonetheless**, if you look at the [headset compatibility guide](http://www.jabra.com/headsets-and-speakerphones/compatibilityguide), the only Dell products compatible with any Jabra product are the Aero, Streak, Venue Pro and the XCD 28.

This leads me to believe the headset is only compatible with mobile devices, not laptops. I'd suggest checking out the web site or contacting support.

Comment: i have this; https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSsKMYrYbuOXzXbd9oEoZiwnK_sepirI0LtPJcDoZktAem9VGZ2gA

Comment: i have macbook and it connects with macbook perfectly and i can transfer sound from macbooom to bluetooth

Comment: That is great that it works with your Macbook, and I'm not surprised considering Apple being a front runner in mobile audio. Unfortunately, just because it is compatible with Apple doesn't mean it will work with everything.